# Shadow content appearing in html and not allowing to get the full value of text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am retrieving some data from a database and displaying it in a text input element. I am setting the data in the text input with the value attribute. I also want to give the user the ability to modify the data. However, when I want to retrieve the user modified data, using the value attribute, I only get the data that was pre-provided by the database, not the user modified version. What the user enters doesn't affect the value attribute. Then I realized that the value attribute isn't changing when the user edits the contents of the text input, but a "Shadow content (User agent)" and a div are the ones that actually contain the contents of the text input. [Here is the html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf3rA.png)

Could anyone tell me how can I access the data that the user modified in the Shadow content (User agent)?

Comment: This is how browsers implement certain elements that have behaviors build in to them. It's a part of the element's composition and inner workings. The User Agent being the browser that you use. You can do it too with the Web Components API. The rest of your question seems kind of vague. Please make a minimal reproducible example for us to examine.

Comment: Are you trying to get the current value of the input? Yes or No?

Comment: YES. The problem is that getAttribute("value") only gives the data that was already put in the text input.

Comment: I understand. You need to get the value from the input **property**, like `document.getElementById("my-input").value` :)

Comment: Instead of `.getAttribute("value")` use `.value`